# UIButtons juxtaposed on top of imageview

Tags: ios, button, storyboard

I have this simple imageView that is the size of my controller. it's pretty much a background.

This background contains visual texts & buttons. I need to interact with these buttons so my idea was to add clear UIButtons on top of my image.

Sounds pretty easy. but i've been playing with constraints and aspect ratios for about 30 minutes and I just can't get them to align properly.

Am I even trying the right thing? If yes, how should I proceed? 
I have an imageView and 3 buttons. I am using storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I think the better approach would be to cut out visual texts and buttons from your background image and put them as a regular UI elements. Then use auto layout, so they displayed correctly on any iOS device.

Comment: Hmmkay, I'll look into that ! It's just such a pain that a graphic designer did all that and i'll just have to do it myself again...

Comment: Graphic designers are expected to export assets in an appropriate manner for use by developers.